# Компьютер выключается при использовании VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, виртуальная-машина

При работе с *Oracle VM VirtualBox* компьтер начинает самопроизвольно выключаться. Подскажите, пожалуйста, из-за чего это может происходить и как это исправить.

Если, что при работе виртуалка максимум ест 34% памяти и 19% ЦП
Операционка *Windows 11*
Процессор *Intel Core i7-1165G7*
16 ГБ оперативки

Виртуальная машина работает под Debian 11

Comment: Мощности не хватает, блок питания или батарейка слабенькие?

Comment: нужно смотреть в протоколах системы. А так просто это гадание на кофейной гуще и даже без гущи.